# IndexedDB - Dexie JS : Dynamically create stores

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I'm working with indexedDB for local data storage, with Dexie.js which is pretty nice as a wrapper, especially because of the advanced queries.
Actually, I would like to create to create several datastore by script, which seem complicated.

To create a new store, you would do something like :

```
db.version(2).stores({
    Doctors: "++" + strFields
});
```

If I do something like Doctors = "Hospital", it still creates the store with a name "Doctors".

Is there a way to do this?

Did anybody faced the same problem?

Comment: The simplest method is to just use the indexedDB API.

Comment: @Josh  - Not really.  I was using the direct API, and gave up on it.  I am liking dexie must better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's say you want three object stores "Doctors", "Patients" and "Hospitals", you would write something like:

```
var db = new Dexie ("your-database-name");
db.version(1).stores({
    Doctors: "++id,name",
    Patients: "ssn",
    Hospitals: "++id,city"
});
db.open();
```

Note that you only have to specify the primary key and the required indexes. Primary key can optionally be auto-incremented ("++" prefixed). You could add as many properties to your objects as you wish without having to specify each one in the index list.

```
db.Doctors.add({name: "Phil", shoeSize: 83});
db.Patients.add({ssn: "721-07-446", name: "Randle Patrick McMurphy"});
db.Hospitals.add({name: "Johns Hopkins Hospital", city: "Baltimore"});
```

And to query different stores:

```
db.Doctors.where('name').startsWithIgnoreCase("ph").each(function (doctor) {
    alert ("Found doctor: " + doctor.name);
});

db.Hospitals.where('city').anyOf("Baltimore", "NYC").toArray(function (hospitals) {
   alert ("Found hospitals: " + JSON.stringify(hospitals, null, 4));
});
```

Comment: Note that if you are releasing a second version to live, you keep all the db.version(1) statements and the appropiate db.version(2) statements.

Comment: These stores are not created dynamically. You have to know what stores you need before creating them. Moreover using new Dexie(dbName) always causes db.verno = 0 so it is not possible to properly increment version dynamically. All of these should be known a priori. Am I right?

Comment: Indexeddb is designed around having statically created stores and Dexie reflects that in the main use cases. In order to att stores dynamically you need to go through a version upgrade. Dexie also supports this use case and it is described here: https://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie.open()#sample-dynamic-mode