# Is dynamically creating object stores on indexeddb good?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I'm new to indexeddb. Consider I have a unique page. That page will have tons of records or objects(50k+) which I have to save. So if I put all those records from different pages to one object store, does this affect the query performance? (consider the store is indexed)
Another option is creating object stores dynamically and querying the corresponding object stores. So I just tried that with dexie.
https://jsfiddle.net/sju8vj5h/

```
var storeName = "s"+new Date().valueOf();
var stores = {};
stores[storeName] = '++id,name,age';
var db = new Dexie("MyFriendDB");
db.version(1).stores(stores);
```

But this doesn't work on running 2nd time. I found that, to add a store dynamically need to change the version and the upgrade will trigger.
So is this a good pattern to add object stores dynamically?
I have already read [IndexedDB - Dexie JS : Dynamically create stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995810/indexeddb-dexie-js-dynamically-create-stores) but that didn't help for this situation.

Comment: As with most performance concerns, the answer will depend largely on the actual uses of the code in question. The best thing to do is pick a way of doing it and measure the performance. Your question on whether this is a "good" pattern is going to be elicit opinions rather than facts, and is therefore off-topic.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks, but I'm looking for both facts and opinions from anyone who crossed through the similar requirement. So if the words good pattern makes you think off-topic I will edit that.

Comment: Basically, SO is not really a good site for these kinds of questions. Take a look at [this Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296542/215552) for an idea of why.